# from c to Mips Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Assume that the variables f, g, h, i, and j are
assigned to registers $s0, $s1, $s2, $s3, and
$s4, respectively. Assume that the base address
of the arrays A and B are in registers $s6 and
$s7, respectively. C Code:

```
B[g] = A[f + 1] + A[f]; 
f = A[f];
```

For the C statements above, what is the
corresponding MIPS assembly code? The two
statements cannot swap order.

```
sll $t0,$s0,2
add $t0,$t0,$s6
lw $t0,0($t0)
lw $t1,4($t0)
add $t2,$t0,$t1
sll $t3,$s1,2
add $t3,$t3,$s7
sw $t2,0($t3)

add $s0,$t0,$zero
```

does my solution is correct ?

I found the solution is different

Comment: [Computer Organizaton and Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75734818) seems to be related to this.

Comment: You have lots of undeclared variables in your C code so I can't tell what the right translation would be.  We need to know the types.  Also, there are two lines of C code here.  Which specific one do you need us to check?  Can we assume `A` and `B` point to separate objects?

Comment: Assuming those arrays are `int32_t[]` then yeah, that's almost right.  It would be better to comment your asm with the C expression for each result, e.g. `A[f]` for the first load.  And `A[f + 1]` for the second load, which is what you intended to do except that the previous instruction actually overwrote `$t0` so you're dereferencing the previous load result.

Comment: Comments on another question about the same code ([Computer Organizaton and Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75734818)) point out that it might not be safe to assume that `B[g]` and `A[f]` aren't the same memory locations, so the final `A[f]` might be a reload of the store.  If they're actually *arrays* in C, like `int A[10], B[12]`, not just pointers like `foo(int *A, int *B)`, then it would be safe to assume they don't alias.

Comment: What was different in the other solution you found?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is wrong.

```
lw $t0,0($t0)
```

loads data from a memory and save what is loaded to the register `$t0`, so after execution this line, `$t0` no longer holds the pointer of an element in the array. Therefore, the next line

```
lw $t1,4($t0)
```

cannot correctly load the desired element from the array.